# getElementById on element from parent component returns null, when called in ngAfterViewInit() of child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I am trying to display dynamic number of charts by loading child components from parent component.

I have created an array `barChart` in Parent where I have the ids `['Canvas0', 'Canvas1'...]`. But I am getting following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null in `var ctx =
>   canvas.getContext("2d");` of Child Component.

Parent HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of barChart; let i = index">
    <app-bar-chart [chart]="chart"  style="border: 2px solid;" ></app-bar-chart>
</div>
```

Child TypeScript:

```
export class BarChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() chart: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.chart)
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //setTimeout(()=>{
    //  this.addchart(this.chart);
    //}, 3000);
    this.addchart(this.chart); 
  }

  public addchart(chartid){
    console.log(chartid);
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById(chartid);
    console.log(document.getElementById(chartid));
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19],
              backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
        },
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="chart">
  <canvas id="{{chart}}" width="400" height="400">{{chart}}</canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you can use **@ViewChild** decorator to query an element from component template

*BarChartComponet*

```js
  @ViewChild('chartElm', { static: true }) public chartElm: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addchart(); 
  }

  public addchart(){
    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> this.chartElm.nativeElement; // 

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19],
              backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
        },
      }
    });
  }
```

*template*

```html
<div style="width:400px; height:100%;"> 
  <canvas #chartElm ></canvas>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-fnpfq8)

Comment: The error is gone but the chart width and height is Nan so its not displayed

Comment: @SwapnilGhosh check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-fnpfq8 I just set a component style like width nd height  or style the paranet elemnt